# Keep angular content on index.html off template pages?

Tags: angularjs, templates, model-view-controller

Is there a way to have the contents of the view page not show on template pages?

Say my index page is to display blog posts and has the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
      <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="WelcomeCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>

 <div class="blog-masthead">
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav">
      <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#/">Home</a>
     <a class="blog-nav-item " href="#/register">Register</a>


    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="article in articles">
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item active">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{article.title}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{article.post}}</p>


</a>
    </div>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="register/register.js"></script>
    <script src="welcome/welcome.js"></script>
    <script src="addPost/addPost.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I goto template pages, for example the register template, the nav and blog posts that are meant for only index.html are showing on the register page as well as all the other templates. (test post)
[image]

Code for register.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">
     <title>AngularJS Blog</title>
     <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="spin.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ladda.min.js"></script>
    <link href="ladda-themeless.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
    <body>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
    <h2>AngularJS Blog!</h2>
  </div>
  <form class="form-signin" name="regForm">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regForm.email.$invalid }">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
    <p class="help-block" ng-show="regForm.email.$invalid">Enter a valid email.</p>
</div> 
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regForm.password.$invalid }">
    <label>Password</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="8">
    <p class="help-block" ng-show="regForm.password.$error.minlength">Min password length is 8 characters.</p>
 <p style="color:red;" ng-show="regError">{{regErrorMessage}}</p>
</div>  
<button type="button" ladda-loading="login.loading" data-style="expand-right" ng-click="signUp();" ng-disabled="!user.email || !user.password" class="btn btn-lg segoe-ui-light ladda-button btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>

    </form>
      </div>
    </body></html>
```

Code for register.js

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.register', ['ngRoute','firebase'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
      });
    }])

    .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope','$location','$firebaseAuth', function($scope,$location,$firebaseAuth) {

$scope.mesg = 'Hello';
     var firebaseObj = new Firebase("myblog-xxx.com");
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);
     var login={};
    $scope.login=login;

    $scope.signUp = function() {
if (!$scope.regForm.$invalid) {
    var email = $scope.user.email;
    var password = $scope.user.password;
    if (email && password) {
login.loading = true;
        auth.$createUser(email, password)
            .then(function() {
                // do things if success
                console.log('User creation success');
                $location.path('/home');
            }, function(error) {
                // do things if failure
                console.log(error);
                $scope.regError = true;
                $scope.regErrorMessage = error.message;
            });
    }
}
    };
      }]);
```

Please let me know if additional information is needed as I'm not sure exactly where the problem lies.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `ng-if ng-show ng-hide` directives

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

`ng-if` is better in terms of performance.

`ng-show` will render an element, and use `display:none` to hide it, `ng-if` will actually remove the element from DOM, and will re-create it, if it’s needed. You may need `ng-show` for an elements that toggles on an off often, but for 95% of the time, `ng-if` is a better way to go.

However, I think your real problem here is that what changes with your route is what `<div ng-view></div>` renders.

> ngView is a directive that complements the $route service by including
>   the rendered template of the current route into the main layout
>   (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included
>   view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route
>   service.

So obviously if you declare other components outside your templates in your index.html, those tags will keep on showing in every view.

For example:

```
<div ng-view></div>

 <div class="blog-masthead">
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav">
      <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#/">Home</a>
     <a class="blog-nav-item " href="#/register">Register</a>


    </nav>
  </div>
```

There, no matter which your template is, the nav bar will be shown.

BTW if you still want to manage it outside your `ng-view` you coud use `ng-if`.
Like this:

```
 <div class="blog-masthead" ng-if="expression">
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav">
      <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#/">Home</a>
     <a class="blog-nav-item " href="#/register">Register</a>


    </nav>
  </div>
```

`expression` should be an evaluatable expression. Take a look at the examples provided by the official documentation.

Comment: can you elaborate where your answer is applicable in my code shown for the solution i'm looking for?  I'm still uncertain what the answer is.  Thanks.